# Can you offer any tips/best practices for running SQL Server on an Amazon EC2 Instance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, cloud

Setting up a Windows based web application on Amazon's cloud has definitely been a learning experience. Lots of unexpected hoops to jump through, especially to get around the limitations associated with ephemeral local drives.

I was hoping to tap into the collective wisdom of those who have walked this road ahead of me and get some insight into best practices and/or tips for running SQL server on an Amazon EC2 Instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing web-directory and SQL Server files in EBS is an easy way to get around the flimsyness of local storage.

I've made a script for backing up SQL-Server to S3:

http://friism.com/ec2-sql-server-backup-strategies-and-tactics

Here are some more general thoughts on running ASP.Net websites off EC2:

http://friism.com/rent-vs-buy-or-ec2-vs-building-your-own-iron

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The EBS is definitely a must, but it is a bit painful, especially when you need to attach it before windows starts (for event logs, AD databases, etc). Still fine tuning my approach.

Comment: No problem.

You don't necessarily have to attach it before Windows starts, Windows has no problems working with volumes attached after boot.

Comment: I think you are mistaken based on my experiments. Windows definitely has problems if the AD database is on a drive that is not attached at startup.

Comment: @JohnFx, yeah your're right. My experiences are limited to non-AD instances with SQL Server files located on EBS.

Answer (score 3):

Brent Ozar is very much into cloud computing and I beleive he has a number of articles on his blog pertaining to this.

Have a search through http://www.brentozar.com/ look for the word cloud.

For example, I came across his tutorial on how to setup hosting on Amazon EC2.

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/10/running-sql-server-2005-on-amazon-ec2/

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. I would be interested to know how you get on using the platform.

Comment: After I get it working I'll probably come back and post my findings. Also thinking about putting up a blog about the whole experience and the things I learned along the way. The documentation for setting up Windows apps is really sparse out there.